# Region server is not running on hadoop 2.0 distributed cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

While starting hbase cluster i was facing below error

```
  2015-05-15 16:58:31,741 WARN  [regionserver60020-    SendThread(hbasenamenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
  2015-05-15 16:58:32,843 INFO  [regionserver60020-SendThread(hbasenamenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server hbasenamenode/172.17.198.59:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
     2015-05-15 16:58:32,847 WARN  [regionserver60020-SendThread(hbasenamenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
   2015-05-15 16:58:33,752 INFO  [regionserver60020] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping server on 60020
   2015-05-15 16:58:33,755 FATAL [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: ABORTING region server demodatanode2clone2,60020,1431689290504: Initialization of RS failed.  Hence aborting RS.
  java.io.IOException: Received the shutdown message while waiting.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.blockAndCheckIfStopped(HRegionServer.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeZooKeeper(HRegionServer.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.preRegistrationInitialization(HRegionServer.java:702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:837)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
  2015-05-15 16:58:33,756 FATAL [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
 2015-05-15 16:58:33,767 INFO  [regionserver60020] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping server on 60020
 2015-05-15 16:58:33,767 INFO  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: Stopping infoServer
 2015-05-15 16:58:33,845 INFO  [regionserver60020] mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60030
  2015-05-15 16:58:33,949 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine: Region server exiting
 java.lang.RuntimeException: HRegionServer Aborted
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:2410)
   2015-05-15 16:58:33,951 INFO  [regionserver60020-SendThread(hbasenamenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server hbasenamenode/172.17.198.59:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
  2015-05-15 16:58:33,953 WARN  [regionserver60020-SendThread(hbasenamenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
    2015-05-15 16:58:33,959 INFO  [Thread-9] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook starting; hbase.shutdown.hook=true; fsShutdownHook=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$ClientFinalizer@36d87f9e
    2015-05-15 16:58:33,972 INFO  [Thread-9] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Starting fs shutdown hook thread.
    2015-05-15 16:58:33,983 INFO  [Thread-9] regionserver.ShutdownHook: Shutdown hook finished.
```

But while looking for the error i got one solution from some site as run this command

```
  bin/hbase zkcli
```

and it worked but i am not getting what this command does? Can any one pls tell me why actually i was facing issue earlier and how above resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Add this property in **hbase-site.xml**:

```
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
        <value>1000</value>
 </property>
```

This property increases the maximum number of client connections.

Default value is **300**. Change it to **1000** to avoid zookeeper ConnectionLoss errors. Also add `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` and `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` properties in slave node's `hbase-site.xml` too.

> **NOTE:** Add this property on both master and slave node. Restart your HBase.

**UPDATE:**

Change your `hbase-site.xml` (in both **master** and **slave** node) as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name>
        <value>master:60000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://NN:PortNo/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>NN,DN</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
            <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
            <value>1000</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

I have same `hbase-site.xml` on all nodes. But you have different files on both master and slave node. This may be a problem in future. Try to maintain all the `hbase-site.xml` files similar.

**UPDATE II:**

1. Delete one entry for `demonamenodeclone2` in master's **regionservers** file. Your regionserver file in master should contain only two lines with one line for master-hostname and other line for slave-hostname.
2. **Regionserver** file on slave node should be same as that on master. But you have only localhost in it. Change it to contain two lines as in master's regionserver file.
3. You are missing a `</property>` in **hbase-site.xml** for `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort`. Change it in slave node too.

Comment: i have changed as u suggested but still its not working same error any other suggestion?

Comment: Post your new files `hbase-site.xml`, `hbase-env.sh` and `regionservers` of master and slave nodes

Comment: Updated answer. Check it. If possible post the exact file contents not the one like `regionservers` file. It wont help you if we cant view your exact files.

Comment: i have update hbase-site.xml as u suggested at both the nodes master and slave but still its not running. Demon for regionserver on datanode2 got started by after few seconds went off. i will share all 3 conf files for both nodes can u come on chat so i can share the files ?

Comment: Updated answer. Try it.

Comment: Rajesh updated point 1 and 2. 3rd was typo mistake here only. But still region server is not up at demodatanode2clone2. As error log says issue with the connection as it says connection refused. Any point you want to say for this ?

Comment: Now while checking error log for zookepper on datanode2clone2. its showing  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. i think my zookepper in not getting up so i have removed zookepper for demodatanode2clone2. Now i have 1 entry in hbase-site.xml for zookeeper then i tried but still at namenode zookeeper log got this type:create cxid:0xcd zxid:0x500000046 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/namespace/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/namespace/hbase

Comment: At datanode [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14d41acb91e0001
INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /IP:57875 which had sessionid 0x14d41acb91e0001
2015-05-11 12:40:57,807 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x4d41acded10000 12:41:10,556 ERROR [LearnerHandler-/IP:46894] quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
java.io.EOFException

Comment: Iam also getting same issue will u please send those config files to this mail, chantijagan001@gmail.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: @RajeshN NN,DN in the hbase.zookeeper.quorum property means we whousl replca those with our name node and data nodes hostnames? or are those values meant to be that way?

Comment: Yes. You have to replace NN and DN with their respective hostnames.